# MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, wolfram-cdf

Is there a way to overcome the problem listed below? I have checked the path of the JavaScript.

## The error message

> The resource from “https://unpkg.com/browse/wolfram-notebook-embedder@0.2.2/dist/wolfram-notebook-embedder.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>
> Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “https://unpkg.com/browse/wolfram-notebook-embedder@0.2.2/dist/wolfram-notebook-embedder.min.js”.

## Relevant Code

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/wolfram-notebook-embedder@0.2.2/dist/wolfram-notebook-embedder.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have checked the path of the javascript

Then you would have seen that the URL you are using is to an HTML document  displaying a nicely formatted rendering of the JavaScript.

You need to load actual JavaScript (without `browse/` in the URL).